# Oxygen-18 in saline water and freshwater

Tags: oxygen, salinity, isotopic

Which has higher $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$, saline water or freshwater?
I searched for this question and found many researches about the relationship between $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$ and salinity. But, I'm not sure why δ18O differs by salinity.
Some researches say that $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$ is high in saline water and low in freshwater.

Why would $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$ differs by salinity, especially of seawater and freshwater?

EDIT: I was just curious if I can determine whether a diadromous fish was anadromous or catadromous by examining $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$ value of the fish fossil.

In [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-03232-9#Fig2) research, how can we know that the fish was anadromous by its $\delta {}^{18} \text{O}$ value?

Comment: It depends on what latitudes the fresh vs saline water samples are drawn from.

Comment: Did you have a visit at NASA' Goddard Institute and the open access  [Global Seawater Oxygen-18 Database](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/o18data/)?

Comment: I found out that δ18O differs by salinity because of precipitation and evaporation. But I'm not sure if it can also be applied to δ18O difference between seawater and freshwater.